# PHP расширение активного класса

Tags: php

Есть несколько классов: A,B,C,D, где А - главный, а B,C,D я ими хочу расширять класс А, не пересоздавая его а просто дополняя, возможно ли такое? чтобы класс А был совокупностью А,B,C,D? (т.е. код D использует функции C, C использует функции A,B).

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.4+: [traits](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php), так называемые подмешивания на уровне языка.
PHP 5.3-: поведения через __set, __get, __call и прочую магию, которые ищут ненайденное свойство или метод в массиве поведений объекта, которые ему добавляются в рантайме. Этим жил Yii 1.x, хотя во втором они вроде тоже сохранились.

В любом случае вы практически наверняка что-то делаете не так, и стоит спросить решение по конкретной задаче. У меня сейчас до 90% классов не имеют родителя вообще, а у остальных уже родитель не имеет родителя, про множественное наследование вообще речи не идет. Если класс выполняет какую-то конкретную функцию (single responsibility principle), то ему никогда не потребуется наследоваться от двух классов, каждый из которых выполняет свою конкретную функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Множественного наследия в PHP нету. Поэтому только один родитель.

Comment: ну возможно-же не через наследование а через костылик?)))) фреймы например инклудят класс за классом (CI например), вот нужно по типу такой схемы.

Comment: @Manitikyl, расширение класса инклудом не расширишь.  
Можно конечно извратиться с `__call` и подгрузкой классов, но надо ли?  
Практика показывает что если нужен костыль - переделай приложение (если, конечно, костыль не для работы самой среды (ух, IE!)).